# Springfox Swagger generating requests with port 80 for HTTPS URLS

Tags: swagger, springfox

I am experiencing an issue using springfox-swagger2 v2.2.0 related to the request padding port 80 for a HTTP URL.

Is there anyway to disable the generation of the port or set the port to 443 programmatically based on a Spring Profile?

Generated CURL:

curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" "https://test.com:80/api/users/search"

Comment: I'm also interested in a solution - same problem here.

Comment: Are u having the service sit behind load balancers that is causing this to happen by any chance?

Comment: @DilipKrishnan That's exactly what I have. I have ELB with SSL point to a server.

Comment: @DilipKrishnan - The services are deployed out to a Pivotal Cloud Foundry instance.

Comment: Upgrading to springfox 2.6.1 and spring 4.2+ will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. It is because Swagger uses a class from Spring Framework which is adding the port 80 to the host property in the /v2/api-docs json response (Check Swagger2Controller.class). I had this issue with spring framework version 4.1.4.Release. Upgrading to latest version 4.3.2.Release fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Hit the same issue, but rather than upgrade the spring framework libraries as per @Akshay answer (thanks for pointing out the Swagger2Controller.class), I added the following property to my application-dev.yml file (replace hostname with your host).

springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.host: hostName:443

Comment: Just recently used this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with spring boot 3.0 and openapi-starter-webmvc-ui 2.0
(My project does sit behind the load balancer)

none of the above answers worked so I tried this:

in my swagger config I added

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        servers = {
                @Server(url = "https://MyProject:443", description = "Default Server URL")
        }
)
```

after this swagger redirected me to 443 port instead of 80.

hope it helps