# Swagger invalid hostname generated for REST endpoints REQUEST url

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

Our application is been deployed inside a DC/OS which is developed using
spring boot (2.0.6.RELEASE) & swagger (2.6.1).

problem we are getting is am accessing swagger via

https://api.example.com/appname/swagger-ui.html This is working fine and returning swagger UI with all our REST endpoints.

When I try to request our API through swagger this hostname is changing to https://api.example.com:80

> Wrong request URL generated by swagger -
> https://api.example.com:80/health
>
> Correct request URL should be https://api.example.com/appname/health

Added screenshot actual domain names are altered.
[image]

Our Config

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class AppConfig {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    }
}
```

**I would like to understand**

- How the hostname is been generated for request URL?
- Why it is not relative path based on the URL accessed?
- How to configure this base url of swagger so that request url can be relative based on the URL used to access swagger.

Comment: `"Whereas when I try to request our API though this hostname is changing to https:api.example.com:80/health"` This part is not clear. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @smilyface I have updated the question with my screen shot and modified description.

Comment: @prem how did you solve this issue. Please see if you could add solution.

Comment: @ShahbazAhmad, Answer gave by Noman Khan has helped me to fix this issue. I have approved that answer as wel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check [Springfox Swagger generating requests with port 80 for HTTPS URLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117478/springfox-swagger-generating-requests-with-port-80-for-https-urls) for similar issue reported

You may set the property

```
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.host=api.example.com
```

or through config api

```
docket.host("your host url")
```

Comment: We have multiple env like

local : http://localhost:8080/
DEV : https://dev.api.example.com/appname
Integration : https://int.api.example.com/appname
PROD : https://prod.api.example.com/appname

is it possible to define with relative URL for this property?

Comment: Great, helpful.