# Spring REST API And OpenApi - Duplicated Context Path Call

Tags: java, spring, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am creating a Spring RESTful API with an openapi starting point. In my openapi I defined the servers property to the localhost (with the port number and the context-path that I'm planning to use) and in my `application.yml` I defined the context path under the property `server.servlet.context-path`, below are snippets of those two files.

`my-api-v1.yaml`:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: My API
  description: The application exposes the my API endpoints to be used using RESTful services.
  version: 0.1.0
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:9001/my-api/v1
    description: Local URL for my RESTful endpoints
tags:
  - name: Users
    description: Users endpoints
paths:
  /users:
    get:
      tags:
        - Users
      summary: Get all users
      description: Retrieve all the users from the database
      operationId: getAllUsers
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserDetail'
                minItems: 0
                maxItems: 20
components:
  schemas:
    UserDetail:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          description: User id
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: 1
        firstName:
          description: User's first name
          type: string
          example: John
        lastName:
          description: User's last name
          type: string
          example: Doe
```

`application.yml`:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.springframework.web: ERROR
    org.hibernate: ERROR
    org.my.api: DEBUG
spring:
  application:
    name: My API
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: always
server:
  address: localhost
  port: 9001
  servlet:
    context-path: /my-api/v1
```

When I run my application, I can't call the users endpoint with what I expect the url would be (that is `http://localhost:9001/my-api/v1/users`), I get a 400 error back.
[image: 400 error single context path]

But if I write the context path twice, it works.
[image: duplicated context path api call works]

If I comment one of them and re-run the application, then I can call the url with the context path written once.
Why is this happening? I am using openapi generator maven plugin to generate the controller and model from my openapi file (with generatorName spring). I checked both openapi generator and spring generator documentations to check if there is something or a property I can use to override the url to use but did not find anything.
How can I fix this so that I can write the context path once in the url and be able to use Try it out button when opening it in swagger-ui.

Comment: That is expected. Setting the `context-path` on a spring-boot application means that all ressoruces should be "under" the `context-path`. The `context-path` acts as global prefix if you so will. See [this article over at `baeldung.com`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-context-vs-servlet-path) for details.

Comment: @Turing85 Sure, but then why would specifying it in the openapi url also add it, making me write it twice to call the api?

Comment: As I said: the `context-path` acts as global prefix. There is no logic. It just prefixes everything. A `context-path` of `foo` and a `@GetMapping(path = "bar")` will create an endpoint `/foo/bar`. Even if the `context-path` and the `path` from the mapping are identical: the `context-path` will prefix the `path` from the mapping.

Comment: Actual question is: why do you set the `context-path`?

Comment: For the first part, even with servlet path instead of context path, I still need to write it twice to call the api, so the issue is including `my-api/v1` in the openapi url. As for why setting the context path, I want to add a prefix path for all the endpoints

Comment: If we want to set a global prefix, we add it as `context-path`. We do not need to add the "common suffix" of the openapi defintion.

Comment: But then how would I define the localhost url in my openapi? I can't just leave it `http://localhost:9001` as it does not reflect the url to use when calling my api. Also if I try to execute it with `Try it out`, it will not work since the url to call is missing the context path, which is why I tried to add it in the first place but got the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get it. You are only talking about the hostname, right? If we use springfox, we can configure the hostname separately, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53929928/4216641) for details.

Comment: Ok, I think I get the idea now, the preview of openapi was from a plugin in my IDE, but I think what the process should be is, the openapi I use is for generating the code, and springfox (or springdoc is what I ended up using) is to generate the openapi documentation that I should actually see and use. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

I could avoid the situation by changing the `my-api-v1.yaml` like this:

```
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:9001
    description: Local URL for my RESTful endpoints
  - url: http://localhost:9001/my-api/v1
    description: Local URL for my RESTful endpoints
```

First line of servers should be without path in order not to duplicate.

You can test with second one.